# Resize div in Angular 6

Tags: angular, resizable

I am working on Angular resize element

using : https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-resizable-element

**My Module**

```
import { ResizableModule } from 'angular-resizable-element';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ResizableModule],
})
```

**My Component TS**

```
import { ResizeEvent } from 'angular-resizable-element';
```

**My Component HTML**

```
<div
    mwlResizable
    [enableGhostResize]="true"
    [resizeEdges]="{bottom: true, right: true, top: true, left: true}"
    (resizeEnd)="onResizeEnd($event)">
</div>
```

When i rezie element its reverting to the old dimension.

i dint configured styles which they suggested in documentation.

i am using styleUrls, where are they given syntax for style, is showing syntax error.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-widgets',
  templateUrl: './widgets.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./widgets.component.scss',
  [mwlResizable] {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

Can any one provide the proper syntax to define styles in my app.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As Angular doc says](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#loading-component-styles), it is not possible to combine `styles` and `styleUrls`:

> By setting styles **or** styleUrls metadata

In addition, you wrote incorrectly attribute in your CSS. It should be in square brackets:

```
[mwlResizable] {
    box-sizing: border-box; 
}
```